# Maven: assembly-plugin is not run at all

Tags: java, maven, packaging

I am pretty new to Maven, tried to learn a couple of times before and figured I was better off without Maven. Now, (un)fortunately I have to use Maven in a project I'd like to contribute to. My problem at this point is regarding the packaging. I'd like to produce a self-contained (aka "fat") jar with all dependencies included, and a colleague who's played around with Maven helped me out with the pom file.

I have checked his pom files, as well as samples here on SO. The xml looks legit but the plugin is not run at all. Note that I get no errors, everything goes fine except I get no "fatjar". Any ideas what might be the cause of this problem?

Below is the relevant portion of the pom.xml. I have seen contradicting code samples with regards to positioning of `<configuration>` and `<executions>` tags, tried pretty much every variation I have found, still no joy.

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.3</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
        <id>make-jar-with-dependencies</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
        <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
        <goals>
            <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <finalName>ProjectName</finalName>
    <appendAssemblyId>true</appendAssemblyId>
    <descriptorRefs>
      <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
    </descriptorRefs>
    <archive>
      <manifest>
        <mainClass>org.mydomain.ProjectName</mainClass>
        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
      </manifest>
    </archive>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**Edit_1** the console output from `mvn clean package` as asked by @khmarbaise

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ myproject ---
[INFO] Deleting /home/user/workspace/project/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ myproject ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 41 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ myproject ---
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 292 source files to /home/user/workspace/project/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ myproject ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/user/workspace/project/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ myproject ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) @ myproject ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /home/user/workspace/project/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Results :
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.3.2:jar (default-jar) @ myproject ---
[INFO] Building jar: /home/user/workspace/project/target/myproject-2.0.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 12.210s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Jun 07 11:45:14 CEST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 18M/184M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: How do you call the project ?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on what you mean, but if I understand correctly you ask how I run the project? I tried both through the terminal and from inside eclipse. No difference...

Comment: Just check if you simply do mvn clean package from console. Can you post the output during the execution on the console?

Comment: Have you define the assembly plugin in pluginManagement block? Can you post you full pom (may be on pastebin) ? Or do you have multi module build?

Comment: Here's the majority of the POM file http://pastebin.com/KxAxwJfh Note that I removed a couple of the java dependencies in respect to original authors' privacy, I am pretty sure they have nothing to do with the problem at hand, so it shouldn't be much of a problem.

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Most of the answer on this page have correct configuration, but the most common mistake I can see is like @khmarbaise said. `build > pluginManagement > plugins > plugin` look extremely like `build > plugins > plugin`, but only the later is actually where you tell the build to act.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I would recommend to create a uberjar by using the [maven-shade-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/), cause it's intention is exactly that purpose. You can do that with the maven-assembly-plugin as well.

So after taking a look into your pom i understand the problem. First you defined the maven-assembly-plugin in the pluginManagement block which will **NOT** execute a plugin furthermore you have defined the maven-assembly-plugin as a dependency separately which is superfluous. Which means simply remove the following from your pom:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.3</version>
   <type>maven-plugin</type>
</dependency>
```

You should define the maven-assembler-plugin like this:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            ...all your configuration here..
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Furthermore i've seen many repository definition which should be handled by repository manager instead. About the repositories in your pom i can recommend reading the [sonatype information](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/02/why-putting-repositories-in-your-poms-is-a-bad-idea/) furthermore you should think about some else will use the project behind a proxy etc. than he has to change you pom to get i working or can't use it cause you defined repositories in your pom he can't reach.

Comment: Any difference between the mentioned plugins? BTW the assembly-plugin should work as well, like you mention, so I am not sure switching to a different plugin would be the magical solution here.

Comment: [re:edit] Putting the plugin as a dependency was a desperate attempt to solve the problem, I can testify that it didn't work before that either. Could you elaborate a bit on your statements regarding the repository definition. (I didn't write the majority of the pom file so I am not sure if it's a bit that I was involved in or something that came with the project)

Comment: Just tried it out, it was indeed the pluginManagement tag that was the crux. oddly enough it was in the original pom file that came with the project, guess the developers havent really tried it... :)

Comment: The pluginManagement tag with the nested plugins was a great catch.  Care must be taken to have a separate <plugins> </plugins> section at the same level as pluginManagement for activation of plugins.  That nesting can get into pom via mvn project creator (e.g. mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DarchetypeVersion=1.4 -DinteractiveMode=false )  which is fine in itself but not the place to prepare plugins for execution.

Answer (score 11):

I had one other view on this problem, that helped me to resolve the %subj%. If you dig the articles about how to make executable jar and jar with dependencies, they usually  provide code snippets, that a newbie tries to copy paste to their pom.xml. Those, that do not know much about the actual structure of pom.xml file (aka me) it is quite difficult task. I ended with this (not working) solution:

```
 <project>
  ......

 <build>
   <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.0</version>
          <configuration>
            ............
          </configuration>

          <executions>
            ..............
          </executions>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

If you know what [pluginManagement](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugin_Management) does, you would not do the same mistake. But for me it was a big unknown and if you never used parent projects, make sure you do not fall into the same trap. With some adjustments here is a working maven-assembly-plugin setup (with the right context in pom.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.blah.blah</groupId>
  <artifactId>some-artifact</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>
   ...
  </dependencies>

  <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId> <!-- nicer looking jar name -->
            <archive>
              <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <mainClass>com.blah.blah.YourMainClass</mainClass>
              </manifest>
            </archive>
            <descriptorRefs>
              <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
          </configuration>

          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>make-assembly</id> 
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Thank you so much David :) I tried changing everything in my pom.xml and assembly.xml multiple times, but still wasn't getting the ZIP, got really irritated!   Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

I want to offer one more suggestion of an error that I had: My xml looked like this:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.maven...</groupId>
        <artifactId>myArtifact</artifact>
        <configuration>
            <descriptorRefs>....</descriptorRefs>
            ...
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    ....
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Whereas the `<executions>` block should be a sibling of the `<configuration>` block, not a child. Soon as I fixed that, my plugin started executing within my build again.

Comment: That is not true according to the documentation (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html). Kindly consider removing your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the **shade** plugin instead (that's the one I use).

**Note the dependencies are included in the final JAR.**

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>standalone-${artifactId}</finalName>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.mypckg.Launcher</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Regards

Comment: Oops, just seens khmarbaise answer, very close.

Answer (score 0):

the dependency looks like

```
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/main/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>attached</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
    </plugin>
```

also you need to define a assembly.xml , here is a example

```
<assembly>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>/lib</outputDirectory>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
    <fileSets>
        <!-- move all the .jar from target to /lib -->
        <fileSet>
            <directory>target</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/lib</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>*.jar</include>
            </includes>
            <!--  include *.jar places the same version of >App.jar
            twice in the lib, we need remove one -->
            <excludes>
                <exclude>App*.jar</exclude>
            </excludes>

        </fileSet>
        <!-- move .bat from scripts to /scripts -->
        <fileSet>
            <directory>src/main/assembly/scripts</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/bin</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>*.bat</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

Comment: Don't want to sound unappreciative but I am pretty sure having a separate XML is not a requirement in this case as I have seen the same code work for different projects on my colleagues computer. Likewise on the plugin homepage they do not mention anything about a separate xml file...

Comment: The attach goal is marked as deprecated and should only be used if called from command line!

Comment: this is A way to get it working, and the best way to get it working in my own opinion (ofc there are other ways).don't know why they deprecated it, clean and easy to read. and it does the job